# Calculating the amount of Dollar-Cents combinations in C++

Tags: c++

Im writing a program that asks the user to enter an amount  of  money   in  the format  of  dollars and remaining   cents which is aimed to calculate and print the minimum number  of  coins (quarters,    dimes,  nickels and pennies) that are equivalent    to  the given amount.

The following is the code that I have, I have managed to successfully calculated the Quarters but not the rest of the cents denominations.

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float dollars, cents;
    int leftover;
    float amount;
    int numberQuarters, numberDimes, numberNickels, numberPennies;

    cout << "Please enter your amount in the form of dollars and cents separated by a space:" << endl;
    cin >> dollars >> cents;
    cout << dollars << " dollars and " << cents << " cents are: " << endl;

    amount = dollars + cents/100;
    leftover = amount;

    numberQuarters = (amount / 25)*100;
    leftover = leftover % 25;

    numberDimes = (leftover/10)*100;
    leftover = leftover % 10;

    numberNickels = (leftover/5)*100;
    leftover = leftover % 5;

    numberPennies = leftover;

    cout << numberQuarters << "Quarters, " << numberDimes << "Dimes " << numberNickels << "Nickels " << numberPennies << "Pennies" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

the result should be (17Quarters, 1Dimes 0Nickels 2Pennies) but instead I get (17Quarters, 0Dimes 0Nickels 4Pennies)

Comment: Why are you using `float` when the input is clearly integer?

Comment: when I used ```int``` the result is ```16Quarters, 0Dimes 0Nickels 4Pennies``` which is even more incorrect @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: And as the answer indicated, that is because you didn't realize that you should be working in cents, not dollars.  The bottom line is that when given an integer-based problem, it is almost always wrong to introduce floating point variables within such a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rather follow this logic, multiply the dollars by 100 rather then dividing the cents by 100, by doing this you will work with `cents` only, it is lot easier to calculate and you will get rid of precision error problem

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int dollars, cents;
    int leftover;
    int amount;
    int numberQuarters, numberDimes, numberNickels, numberPennies;

    cout << "Please enter your amount in the form of dollars and cents separated by a space:" << endl;
    cin >> dollars >> cents;
    cout << dollars << " dollars and " << cents << " cents are: " << endl;

    amount = (dollars*100) + cents;
    leftover = amount;

    numberQuarters = (amount / 25);
    leftover = leftover % 25;

    numberDimes = (leftover/10);
    leftover = leftover % 10;

    numberNickels = (leftover/5);
    leftover = leftover % 5;

    numberPennies = leftover;

    cout << numberQuarters << "Quarters, " << numberDimes << "Dimes " << numberNickels << "Nickels " << numberPennies << "PenIf your inputs are in integer then ynies" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your recommendation, I was trying to match the dollar to cents which I imagined makes the equation complicated as I have to introduce float. Thank you